# Impact on the price does not appear in prestashop CSV

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am using Prestashop 1.6 and I want to modify the prices with a CSV file but I can not do it since in the list of options per column I do not see the impact of Impact on the price.

I already tried with the price columns with IVA, price without IVA, etc. but no option modifies the price.

What I can do?[image]

Answer (score 0):

In fact this field does not exist, so either you get the old price, and you add the impact, or you directly add the new price, or you do a development yourself to handle this.

Regards